# Need all matching values and unmatching from join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using join to get all values from all table but it show all matching columns in all rows.

I tried below query :

```
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A.emp_code) AS SNo, 
cast(datepart(dd,A.att_date) as int) as Attdate
A.att_date,b.emp_code as EmpNo,A.in_time,A.out_time,dbo.late_set.remark
FROM dbo.Daily_attendance_data A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.employee B  ON (A.emp_id = B.emp_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.departments tt ON (B.dept_id = tt.dept_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.groups ON (B.group_id=dbo.groups.group_id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.late_set ON (B.emp_id=dbo.late_set.emp_id) 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.companies ON B.company_id= dbo.companies.company_id
                  where att_date between '2019-01-02' 
and '2019-01-05' and( a.emp_id=2 or a.emp_id=46 or a.emp_id=28)
```

But I get output like below:

```
1   2019-01-03  1002    NULL    NULL    Due to Bus BreakDown
2   2019-01-02  1002    2019-01-02 07:06:49.000 NULL    Due to Bus BreakDown
3   2019-01-04  1002    NULL    NULL    Due to Bus BreakDown
4   2019-01-05  1002    2019-01-05 07:00:05.000 NULL    Due to Bus BreakDown
5   2019-01-05  1018    2019-01-05 07:05:45.000 NULL    Sick
6   2019-01-04  1018    NULL    NULL    Sick
7   2019-01-03  1018    NULL    NULL    Sick
8   2019-01-02  1018    2019-01-02 07:04:23.000 NULL    Sick
9   2019-01-03  1024    NULL    NULL    Casual
10  2019-01-04  1024    NULL    NULL    Casual
11  2019-01-05  1024    2019-01-05 07:02:35.000 NULL    Casual
12  2019-01-02  1024    2019-01-02 07:05:02.000 NULL    Casual
```

Late Set table

```
leave_id    emp_id  start_date  remark  
    4         2    2019-01-02   Due to Bus BreakDown    
    5        46    2019-01-05   Sick    
    6        28    2019-01-02   Casual
```

Daily_attendance_data table:

```
2019-01-02  28  1024    1024    RAVEENDRAN K    2019-01-02 07:05:02.000
2019-01-02  46  1018    1018    ZAIDALAVI KODIYIL   2019-01-02 07:04:23.000
2019-01-03  28  1024    1024    RAVEENDRAN K    NULL
2019-01-04  28  1024    1024    RAVEENDRAN K    NULL
2019-01-05  28  1024    1024    RAVEENDRAN K    2019-01-05 07:02:35.000
2019-01-03  2   1002    1002    AJAYAN NADESAN  NULL
2019-01-02  2   1002    1002    AJAYAN NADESAN  2019-01-02 07:06:49.000
2019-01-03  46  1018    1018    ZAIDALAVI KODIYIL   NULL
2019-01-04  2   1002    1002    AJAYAN NADESAN  NULL
2019-01-04  46  1018    1018    ZAIDALAVI KODIYIL   NULL
2019-01-05  2   1002    1002    AJAYAN NADESAN  2019-01-05 07:00:05.000
2019-01-05  46  1018    1018    ZAIDALAVI KODIYIL   2019-01-05 07:05:45.000
```

My expected output as

```
1   2019-01-03  1002    NULL    NULL    -
2   2019-01-02  1002    2019-01-02 07:06:49.000 NULL    Due to Bus BreakDown
3   2019-01-04  1002    NULL    NULL    -
4   2019-01-05  1002    2019-01-05 07:00:05.000 NULL    -
5   2019-01-05  1018    2019-01-05 07:05:45.000 NULL    Sick
6   2019-01-04  1018    NULL    NULL    -
7   2019-01-03  1018    NULL    NULL    -
8   2019-01-02  1018    2019-01-02 07:04:23.000 NULL    -
9   2019-01-03  1024    NULL    NULL    -
10  2019-01-04  1024    NULL    NULL    -
11  2019-01-05  1024    2019-01-05 07:02:35.000 NULL    -
12  2019-01-02  1024    2019-01-02 07:05:02.000 NULL    Casual
```

I tried but it is giving same values in all columns.